# WPF Control OnRender overriding

Tags: c#, wpf

Just to test how to draw on top of other controls within OnRender, I've created my own control based on TextBox, and decide to override it's OnRender method. But seems it never called.

Here is simple class I've got:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnRender");
        //base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, bounds);
    }
}
```

I declared this class in XAML:

```
<local:MyTextBox Height="118" Margin="10,300,10,10" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" AcceptsReturn="True" Padding="0,0,200,0" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

But there's no signs that OnRender called even one time. What's I'm missing? What the best option to do custom drawing on top of other control ?

Comment: Did you try changing the appearance using ControlTemplate? I feel you need to explore more on the features available on WPF. OnRender is more from the WinForm World

Comment: You might want to look into [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx) for drawing over controls. In case what you're trying to is for validation purposes, have a look at [this article](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/).

Comment: Actually I'm from Cocoa World. Some concepts fron WPF very new to me :-(

Answer (score 4):

You should override the default `Textbox` style...

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof (MyTextBox);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("OnRender");
         //base.OnRender(drawingContext);
         Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
         Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
         drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, bounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works (yellow rectangle), but editing is not possible now.

Comment: You need to be clear with the control's overriding its structure... You have changed the `Textbox`'s Structure and looking for `Textbox` seems good?

Comment: When uncommenting base.OnRender, I just expected the same behaviour just with rectangle on top of TextBox. But seems there's more parts involved in the process.

Comment: If you need a Rectange over the Textbox, just add the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` to the `Textbox`...